# Decrease distance between max and min

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics

Let $a:=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n) \in  \mathbb{Z}^n $ and $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, with

$$f:
\begin{cases} 
\hfill \mathbb{Z}^n \times \mathbb{N}^* \hfill &\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n \\
\hfill ((a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n), k) \hfill & \mapsto  (b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)\\
\end{cases}$$

$f$ satisfies the following constraints:

1. $(\forall b_{i=1,2,\ldots,n}\in \mathbb{Z})(\exists! a_{j=1,2,\ldots,n}\in \mathbb{Z}): b_i= a_j \pm k$
2. $b_{\max} - b_{\min} \le  a_{\max} - a_{\min}$

The task is to find a function $f$(or an algorithm) that satisfies the listed constraints. Could anyone give some hints how can I deal with this problem?

**Examples:**

*Example 1:*
$$f((1,7),4)=(5,3)$$
First constraint:
$$5 = 1 + 4$$
$$3 = 7 - 4$$

Second constraint:
$$5 - 3 \le 7 - 1$$

*Example 2:*
$$f((1,2,3,4,5,6,7),5)=(6,7,\ldots,12)$$
First constraint:
$$6 = 1 + 5$$
$$7 = 2 + 5$$
$$\vdots$$
$$12 = 7 + 5$$
Second constraint:
$$12 - 6 \le 7 - 1$$

---

I tried to solve this problem algorithmically. The following is an implementation using *JAVA*

```
public class MinDiff 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int A[] = {1,7};
        int k = 4;
        System.out.println("Input a:=" + Arrays.toString(A) + ", k:=" + k);
        int d = find(A, k);
        System.out.println("Output a´:=" + Arrays.toString(A));
        System.out.println("Maximum difference is " + d);
    }

    private static int find(int a[], int k) 
    {       
        Arrays.sort(a);

        int n = a.length;
        System.out.println("Maximum difference is " + (a[n - 1] - a[0]));

        if (k >= a[n - 1] - a[0])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                a[i] += k;
            return a[n - 1] - a[0];
        }

        a[0] = a[0] + k;
        a[n - 1] = a[n - 1] - k;

        int max = Math.max(a[0], a[n - 1]);
        int min = Math.min(a[0], a[n - 1]);

        for (int index = 1; index < n - 1; index++) 
        {
            if (a[index] < min)
                a[index] += k;
            else if (a[index] > max)
                a[index] -= k;
            else if ((a[index] - min) > (max - a[index]))
                a[index] -= k;
            else
                a[index] += k;

            max = Math.max(a[index], max);
            min = Math.min(a[index], min);
        }

        return  max - min;
    }
```

The above implementation fail to give a solution for the following input: 
$$a:=(1,2,\ldots,7) \text{ and } k:=5$$

Generally I´m interedted in the following questions: Let $a:=(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n \text{ and } k \in \mathbb{N}^*$

- What is the minimal distance that can we achieve? Could we answer this  question a priori?
- Could we also a priori answer the following question: Does $k$ lead $a$ to an increase or decrease(the $2^{th}$ constraint)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: @Raphael What have you tried? I solved a part of the problem algorithmically(I will update my post to publish that). Where did you get stuck? I would mention that in the update. We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding: If you read my question carefully I did not ask for an **answer** instead for **hints**. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is: I clearly defined the problem provided some examples illustrating the inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, asking for hints doesn't really fix the fundamental issues with such a question.  2. Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Comment: 3. I can't tell what constraint 1 is trying to say.  What does the notation $\forall b_{i=1,2,\ldots,n}\in \mathbb{Z}$ mean?  I know what the notation $\forall b \in \mathbb{Z}$ means, but I have no idea how to interpret that subscript.  Can you rephrase, without using that notation in the subscript?  4. Also, can you elaborate what $\exists!$ means?  I can think of two different meanings (there is a single value for $a_j$ that makes the statement valid; or, out of all of $a_1,\dots,a_n$, there is a single $j$ such that $a_j$ makes the statement valid).  Please edit to clarify.   Thank you!

Comment: 4. If I understand correctly, there is no $f$ that satisfies all of the constraints.  What is the value of $f((1,1,1),42)$ supposed to be?  There seems to be no acceptable value for $f$ on this input.  What about $f((0,20),10)$?  Again, there seems to be no acceptable output for this input.

Comment: 5. What does it mean to "a priori answer"?  If you have an algorithm for this problem, just run it, and it'll tell you whether $a_j$ was increased or decreased.  Why doesn't that count as an answer?  If it doesn't, what exactly are you looking for?